# What is the return value of the function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int, int);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a = 2, b = 3;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, add(a, b));
    return 0;
}

int add(int a, int b) {
    int c = a + b;
    return;
}
```

**The output of the above program is 2 3 5 how can the add function return c without explicitly returning it**

Comment: XY problem: why don't you want to return c ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i just wanted to know how c is returned without explicitly stating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @P.P.'s answer is right: that's an undefined behaviour.

What really happens, instead it strongly depends on the compiler implementation.
The most likely scenario is that the caller function will take a return value anyway. Since the callee function does not return any value, that means the caller function will take a "random"-dirty value from the stack.

I'm going to provide you an example with GCC compiler (without any optimisations):

This is the assembly code for the function `add`:

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
mov    %esi,-0x18(%rbp)
mov    -0x14(%rbp),%edx
mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax
add    %edx,%eax
mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
nop
nop
pop    %rbp
retq
```

As you can see, the addition is performed, stored in the `c` variable.
The result value is luckily stored in `%eax` register, but this has not been done for purpose.

Here there is the assembly code of the *correct* function:

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
mov    %esi,-0x18(%rbp)
mov    -0x14(%rbp),%edx
mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax
add    %edx,%eax
mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax   <====
pop    %rbp
retq
```

As you can see, the value stored in `c` is properly moved in the `%eax` register (with the instruction marked with the `<====`).

In the `main` function (the caller), instead, the assembly is:

```
callq  0x400542 <add>
mov    %eax,%ecx
```

As you can see the caller function, after the call of the function, take the "return value" which is supposed to be in `%eax` register.

This means despite the fact that callee function returns actually a value or not, the *caller* function will takes a return value anyway.

In the example I've just shown you, the return value the caller takes is `%eax` register.

In conclusion if the *callee* function does not return a proper value the *caller* function (main) will take anyway what is stored in `%eax` register (which can be a dirty value if the callee does not return proper a value).

Answer (score 5):

It's [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When a function that's supposed to return a value doesn't do so *and* the caller uses the return value, it's *undefined*. Anything you might observe is purely accidental/platform specific behaviour and not be relied upon. The C standard certainly makes no guarantees.

From C11 draft, [6.9.1 Function definitions/12](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12):

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the
>   function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: you could explain that the value is probably in the stack and took as return valude but it's pure luck and implementation dependent.